# Get HTML and Display it in WebView perfectly

Tags: java, android, jquery

I'm wanting to know if its possible to get the HTML from a webpage in Java/Android so that when I place it into a WebView it loads exactly the same as if I went to the website through Chrome App on phone?

Here is the current code i've tried.

```
public String GetHTML(String xURL) {

        String s = "";

        try {

            String myUri = "http://google.com";
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(myUri);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

            // Build up result
            String bodyHtml = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            s = bodyHtml;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return s;
    }
```

Currently it just returns "S" to be loaded into the WebView by...

```
 webView.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

The code above pulls the HTML down normally for like google.com... when its displayed, all the CSS/Javascript and everything else isn't showing up on the page.  Its just showing it as if there is no HTML or anything related.

Even when I reference to a page where all the actual javascript paths are included in the source, it stil doesn't load it.

What am I missing? and NO i don't want to use webView.loadUrl(theURL);

My ultimate goal is to be able to push the HTML directly into the WebView itself so I can still do everything with CSS and maybe even JQuery if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I came up with was to save all the scripts and css that was referenced needs to be saved locally in the Assets folder. Then, do either a "find and replace" to replace the URLs with the scripts in the main page with the local URLs, or to attempt to save the HTML page locally to the assets folder first after saving all the scripts to the same folder.